# How to alter formula in Excel VBA to make dynamic for rows?

Tags: excel, if-statement, hardcoded, vba

I have a formula (IF statement) I wrote which is completely functional:

```
Formula = "=IF(R3C5=""Feb"",Actuals!R133C35,IF(R3C5=""Mar"",SUM(Actuals!R133C35:R133C36),IF(R3C5=""Apr"",SUM(Actuals!R133C35:R133C37),IF(R3C5=""May"",SUM(Actuals!R133C35:R133C38),IF(R3C5=""Jun"",SUM(Actuals!R133C35:R133C39),IF(R3C5=""Jul"",SUM(Actuals!R133C35:R133C40),IF(R3C5=""Aug"",SUM(Actuals!R133C35:R133C41),IF(R3C5=""sep"",SUM(Actuals!R133C35:R133C42),IF(R3C5=""Oct"",SUM(Actuals!R133C35:R133C43),IF(R3C5=""Nov"",SUM(Actuals!R133C35:R133C44),IF(R3C5=""Dec"",SUM(Actuals!R133C35:R133C45),"""")))))))))))*1000"
```

The problem is, I have hardcoded the rows for the IF function. The initial cell I am referencing `(R3C5)` does not need to be altered. However, Any time I reference row 133, I need that to be dynamic as this row might change every month. I need it to reference the last used row in the sheet. The columns do not need to be dynamic, just the row. How would I go about this?

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/excel-vba/918/methods-for-finding-the-last-used-row-or-column-in-a-worksheet#t=201708101417458076783) to get last row with data. Then pass the row number as a variable into formula.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman I ended up with: `Dim LR As Long` `LR = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Row`. How do I input that into the if statement now? Like this? : ....Actuals!'LR'C35....?

Comment: `... ,Actuals!R" & lRow & "C35,IF`

Answer (score 0):

Answer:

```
Dim LR As Long
Dim sLongFormula$
 Set sourceSheet = Worksheets("Actuals")
        With sourceSheet
        LR = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Row
        sLongFormula = "=IF(Pivot!R3C5=""Feb"",Actuals!R" & LR & "C35,IF(Pivot!R3C5=""Mar"",SUM(Actuals!R" & LR & "C35:R" & LR & "C36),IF(Pivot!R3C5=""Apr"",SUM(Actuals!R" & LR & "C35:R" & LR & "C37),IF(Pivot!R3C5=""May"",SUM(Actuals!R" & LR & "C35:R" & LR & "C38),IF(Pivot!R3C5=""Jun"",SUM(Actuals!R" & LR & "C35:R" & LR & "C39),IF(Pivot!R3C5=""Jul"",SUM(Actuals!R" & LR & "C35:R" & LR & "C40),IF(Pivot!R3C5=""Aug"",SUM(Actuals!R" & LR & "C35:R" & LR & "C41),IF(Pivot!R3C5=""Sep"",SUM(Actuals!R" & LR & "C35:R" & LR & "C42),IF(Pivot!R3C5=""Oct"",SUM(Actuals!R" & LR & "C35:R" & LR & "C43),IF(Pivot!R3C5=""Nov"",SUM(Actuals!R" & LR & "C35:R" & LR & "C44),IF(Pivot!R3C5=""Dec"",SUM(Actuals!R" & LR & "C35:R" & LR & "C45),"""")))))))))))*1000"
        End With
```